# uninitialized constant ActionController::Caching::Sweeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

When precompiling production environment I receive an **uninitialized constant ActionController::Caching::Sweeper** error (same with heroku). In the development environment and with localhost everything is working fine. Thx for any suggestions.

```
C:\Sites\code\myapp>bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/spree_reviews-5447d2231446/app/models/spree/review_sweeper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
C:in `eager_load!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Sites/code/farmfood/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3/lib/polyglot.rb:63:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a [bug in the `rails-observers` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/issues/4). [The bug has been fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/pull/24), but the fix has not yet reached [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-observers).

Use the version of `rails-observers` from [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers), by replacing this line in your [`Gemfile`](http://bundler.io/gemfile):

```
gem 'rails-observers'
```

With this one:

```
gem 'rails-observers', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails-observers.git'
```

Comment: This is now two years later, and we've yet to see the fix in rubygems.org? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's 2018 and still not fixed :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `rails-observers`. https://github.com/rails/rails-observers/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

Thx @khustochka to bringing me on the right track

I solved my problem with:

Installing the gem `'rails-observers'`
https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

Then I added to production.rb

```
  config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task
  config.active_record.observers = :contact_observer
```

Since I got uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Observer error

I created in app/models the file contact_observe.rb

```
 class ContactObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   observe :user
 end
```

after I did `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`
and `rake asset precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

and my problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the spree_reviews extension is depending on a feature of Rails which has been removed in Rails 4. Please file an issue on that project about this problem.